# Jenkins Job Can't find JDK but JDK configured in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jvm

I have been trying to create a test job on Jenkins but I've been getting JRE error. Idea is simple:

1)job will run a simple test command "mvn clean test"
2)Allure report plug-in will generate test based on test results.

I can't get results generated on Jenkins job.

However when I run "mvn clean test" command on command line. I don't get any errors, test results are generated. I can see maven and JDK path is correct when I run following pipeline.

```
node('master') {
    stage ('Run tests')
    dir ('C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/ProjectDirectory') {
        try {
            bat '''mvn -version'''
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE' }
        finally {
            stage ('Publish report')
            step([$class: 'AllureReportPublisher', includeProperties: false, jdk: 'jdk-1.8', results: [[path: '/target/surefire-reports']]]) 
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\ProjectDirectory>mvn -version 
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\3rd_party\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_191, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_191
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows server 2016", version: "10.0", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

If I run tests in the Jenkins pipeline, I get following error.

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.942 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-07T14:51:07Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project restassuredcourse: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

I have correct JDK path in Manage Jenkins > Configure System.
[image]

If I execute "mvn -version" in Jenkins pipeline. I can see Jenkins machine can access correct path.

Comment: 2 things,
You can try with `JAVA_HOME` set to `C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jdk1.8.0_191` to have path w/o space in it.
And if install is complete, you can 'uncheck' Install automatically option & see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

On my local Jenkins I do not declare any JDK in the Jenkins Configurations.

Try to remove the JDK in Jenkins Configuration and Jenkins will use the JAVA_HOME path from your operation system.

Comment: Hello I removed JDK from Jenkins Configuration. Results are the same. 
In system environments JAVA_HOME path was same with Manage Jenkins> JDK anyway.

Comment: Does printing `%PATH%` shows up `JAVA_HOME` directory correctly where `javac` sits under `bin/` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Just to check I generated gradle.build file and instead of executing "mvn clean test" . I used "gradlew clean test" and it worked. The problem is with maven but I couldn't understand why maven does not use system JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert in this. I solved my problem using following steps in linux:

1. edit bashrc file

sudo nano ~/.bashrc

2. add java path in the file like:

JAVA_HOME = /path to jdk

3. save file and run the bashrc script.

source ~/.bashrc

*I did removed jdk path entered in jenkins so it took from system.*
Hope this things will work for you